# magento2 Schedule new update is not working

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, magento-2.0, magento2.1.5, magento-enterprise-2

I have installed Magento 2 freshly and Create a schedule for product attribute value update using "Schedule new update". 
In staging dashboard it shows but even after time cross the starting time it is not activating as result product attribute value is not updating in frontend.

[image]

Even i ran cron for staging.

```
php bin/magento cron:run --group="staging"
```

Still it shows the same result.

Please help me for resole this.

Comment: Have you found it's the reason?

Comment: Having same issue with 2.4.1-p1

Answer (score 4):

It is possible that one of the staging cron jobs is "freezed" (in "running" status in cron_schedule table), most likely it is 'staging_apply_version' job: cron checks the task and since it's in running state it does not start nor is it set to 'failed' because it is considered to be in progress but in fact it is stuck and cannot get completed. Try to remove this job physically or change its status in database directly.

Answer (score 0):

You should run this cron group also :

php bin/magento cron:run --group="magento_staging"